# Insert some data from a listview into a ms access database in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, listview, ms-access

i am trying to insert my listview items into my MS access database.

here is the code:

```
Public newConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Inbox.Accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Private Sub btnNewSMS_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNewSMS.Click

    cn.ConnectionString = newConn
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        cn.Open()

        For x = 0 To ListView2.Items.Count - 1

            Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO InboxTable (Contact_Name,Contact_Number,DateAndTime,Message) Values ('" & ListView2.Items(x).SubItems(0).Text & "', '" & ListView1.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text & "','" & ListView1.Items(x).SubItems(2).Text & "','" & ListView1.Items(x).SubItems(3).Text & ")"

            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

            With cmd
                .CommandText = sqlQuery
                .Connection = cn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()


            End With
            MsgBox("Messages Saved")
            ListView2.Items.Clear()

            'End With

        Next

    End If
    cn.Close()


End Sub
```

my error is:

Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'

my problem is in inserting the values. Please Help me... thanks everyone - Chris

Comment: i change my code because the first one is very terrible... sorry for that..

here is my new new code and new error (Value of '0' is not valid for 'index')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Try this.. 

Public newConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Inbox.Accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"


Private Sub btnNewSMS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewSMS.Click


    For Each x As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO InboxTable (Contact_Name,Contact_Number,DateAndTime,Message) Values ('" & _
                        x.SubItems(0).Text & "', '" & _
                        x.SubItems(1).Text & "','" & _
                        x.SubItems(2).Text & "','" & _
                        x.SubItems(3).Text & "')"
        'Add also the last single qoute before the parenthesis ^_^
        'to make sure the query works..
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

        With cmd
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = cn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MsgBox("Messages Saved")
        ListView2.Items.Clear()

        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Diaton... it is working now.. i see that my problem is the single quote and listview2. (i put listview1 in the values) ... God bless sir... :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code for more than one form’s**
**DataTransfer.vb**

```
Public Class DataTransfer

Public Sub ListToData(ByVal strcon As String, ByVal strcmd As String, ByVal listview As ListView)
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim k As Integer = 0
Dim item As New ListViewItem
Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strcon)
Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strcmd, con)
Try
MessageBox.Show(listview.Items.Count)
  While i < listview.Items.Count
      item = New ListViewItem()
      item = listview.Items(i).Clone
      itemToString(item, strcmd)
      con.Open()
      cmd.CommandText = strcmd
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      MessageBox.Show("saved")
      i += 1
      End While
Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try
 MessageBox.Show(strcmd)
End Sub

Private Sub itemToString(ByVal item As ListViewItem, ByRef strcmd As String)
Dim k As Integer = 1
strcmd += "VALUES ("
strcmd += "'" & item.Text & "'"
MessageBox.Show("subitems" + item.SubItems.Count.ToString)
While k < item.SubItems.Count
strcmd += ",'" & item.SubItems(k).Text & "'"
k += 1
End While
strcmd += ")"
End Sub

End Class
```

**Form1.vb**

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim datatransfer As New DataTransfer
Dim con As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\schoolDB.accdb"
Dim cmd As String = "INSERT INTO Stu_Info  (C_ID, ADM_No, S_Name)"
datatransfer.ListToData(con, cmd, ListView1)
End Sub
End Class
```